# Reading youtube name PHP bringing symbols?

Tags: php, unicode, youtube, symbols

I'm trying to read certain videos names off of youtube, I have it working correctly, although it seems that certain symbols will show as other weird symbols. (Unicode I think??)

```
function get_youtube_title($video_id){
    $url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$video_id;

    $page = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($page);

    $title_div = $doc->getElementById('eow-title');
    $title = $title_div->nodeValue;

    return $title;
}

echo get_youtube_title('e3Nl_TCQXuw');
```

I should be getting "Beauty and the Beast - US Official Final Trailer"

Instead I'm getting "Beauty and the Beast â US Official Final Trailer"

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can use the **mb_convert_encoding()** function?

Comment: Your page is not in UTF-8? What do you read in your browser in Display > Text encoding or similar?

Comment: @julp I have <meta charset="UTF-8"> at the top of my page, and I've tried header("content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");  in php, but still not working.

Comment: The source seems to be in UTF-8 but DOM/libxml2 seems to see it as ISO-8859-1 and then convert it to UTF-8 so the `–` (U+2013, encoded in UTF-8 by 0xE2, 0x80, 0x93) becomes the 3 code points U+E2, U+80, U+93 (= in UTF-8 : , 0xC3, 0xA2, 0xC2, 0x80, 0xC2, 0x93). I may have found 2 workarounds: 1) add a BOM before (`$page = "\u{FEFF}" . file_get_contents($url);`) or 2) XML prolog before (`$page = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'file_get_contents($url);`) - 3) add both (but BOM first, of course).